# Button Onclick Event is not firing using Asp.net Web forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Button Onclick Event is not firing using Asp.net Web forms. If I keep CausesValidation="false" then only button is firing and If I will keep CausesValidation="false" then require field validator not showing message and going to submitting.

Below is my code.

```
   <div class="form-group" style="background: #f1f1f1; padding: 16px 16px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_comments" require="Enter Commnents" class="form-control" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" placeholder="Comments"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <span class="error-msg">
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="all" runat="server" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Enter Comments" ControlToValidate="txt_comments"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                    <br />

                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="all" CssClass="btn btn-primary pull-right" OnClick="lnk_Submit_Click" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>

                                    <span class="error-msg">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Msg2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Below is C# code.

```
protected void lnk_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//code
}
```

I have also javascript code in my page:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateCheckBoxes(source, args) {
        var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= gv_TotalAllReg.ClientID %>');
        var counter = 0;
        var inputs = gridView.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var elementRef = inputs[i];
            if ((elementRef.type == 'checkbox') && (elementRef.checked == true)) {
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
    function selectAll(invoker) {

        var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
            var myElement = inputElements[i];
            // Filter through the input types looking for checkboxes
            if (myElement.type == "checkbox") {
                // Use the invoker (our calling element) as the reference 
                //  for our checkbox status
                myElement.checked = invoker.checked;

            }

        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: how is the JavaScript related? There's nothing in your sample ASPX markup that would trigger it. There aren't even any checkboxes in your ASPX. Do you actually understand what the code is for? Anyway, presumably, when you set `CausesValidation= true`, and press Submit, then previously you had entered data into the Comments? Because otherwise you will inevitably fail validation and your click event will not happen. Perhaps some JS error on your page is stopping .NET from updating the UI to show the error? Hard to know. Check your console. Also on server-side you should check page is valid too

Comment: Lastly: `require="Enter Commnents"` - what is this supposed to be? It does not appear to be a valid attribute for an `<asp:TextBox` (and it contains a spelling error, FYI).